# fast ways of parsing lists of numbers

Tags: r

I've got a column in a CSV file that looks like `c("","1","1 1e-3")` (i.e. white space seperated).  I'm trying to run through all values, taking the `sum()` of values where there is at least one value and returning `NA` otherwise.

My code currently does something like this:

```
x <- c("","1","1 2 3")
x2 <- as.numeric(rep(NA,length(x)))
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  si <- scan(text=x[[i]],quiet=TRUE)
  if (length(si) > 0)
    x2[[i]] <- sum(si)
}
```

I'm struggling to make this fast; `x` is really a set of columns from a CSV file containing a few hundred thousand rows and thought it should be possible to do this in R.

(these are thinned samples from the posterior of a reversible jump MCMC algorithm, hence combining multiple values as the dimensionality changes throughout the file and I want useful columns).

Comment: I don't understand what "`x` is really a set of columns" means.  Can you provide an example of the first few rows/columns of your CSV?

Comment: Hi Joshua, `x` is just one column.  I.e. I'm running the above in something like `apply(mytable[,mycols], 2, function(x) ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to perform a bit faster and may work for you.

```
#define a helper function
f <- function(x) sum(as.numeric(x))
unlist(lapply((strsplit(x3, " ")), f))
#-----
[1] 0 1 6
```

This will return a zero instead of NA, but maybe that isn't a deal breaker for you?

Let's see how this scales to a larger problem:

```
#set up variables
x3 <- rep(x, 1e5)
x4 <- as.numeric(rep(NA,length(x3)))
#initial approach
system.time(for (i in 1:length(x3)) {
  si <- scan(text=x3[[i]],quiet=TRUE)
  if (length(si) > 0)
    x4[[i]] <- sum(si)
})
#-----
   user  system elapsed 
   30.5     0.0    30.5 

#New approach:
system.time(unlist(lapply((strsplit(x3, " ")), f)))
#-----
   user  system elapsed 
   0.82    0.01    0.84
```

Comment: It's the handling of empty lists that was indeed the important thing.  I guess I should just handle that case explicitly.  Something like:

  `sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) if (length(x) == 0) NA else sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: @SamMason - are there times when 0 could be a valid sum? If not, letting it return 0 and then setting it to NA may be faster, i.e. `out[out == 0] <- NA`

Comment: there shouldn't be; but I'd like to know about it if there were.  I.e. all values should be >0, but I want my code to fail noisily should that invariant be broken.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the idea from @Chase, but handling NA and also avoiding a name for the helper function:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, " "),
              function(v)
                if (length(v) > 0)
                  sum(as.numeric(v))
                else
                  NA
      )      )
```

Comment: sorry, your response came between my seeing Chase's response and me replying, we got to the same thing.  What's the convention on SO for saying that both are good answers.

Comment: @SamMason, don't have that much experience myself yet. I guess upvoting both is the logical first step. After that, we could either edit one and delete the other, or simply keep both as they are. Don't worry about which one is the accepted one; there can only ever be one of those, and Chase has definitely earned this one here.